# Function to stall for time with <Windows.h> and continue to other functions

Tags: c++, sleep

My waitSeconds() functions takes an integer for the number of seconds to wait. I am using the  to use Sleep(msec)and converting to seconds at this point I want to try doing it like this and know it's not elegant. However my programs does not execute the rest of my functions calls and I am head banging.

Ultimately, what I want to use this functions call for is to call it with my slowTriangle() function and distressCall() that loops forever with a pause of what the parameter of waitSeconds has been passed through. I hope this last part is making sense. Anyways thank you for any guidance any of you experienced members can provide.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int dots(int count);
int dashes(int count);
void sendSOS();
void waitSeconds(int seconds2Wait);
int triangle(int rows);
int slowTriangle();
void distressCall();

int main()
{
    dots(3);
    dashes(3);
    sendSOS();
    cout << "\n\n ";
    waitSeconds(1);
    int triangle(4);
    int slowTriangle();
    void distressCall();

    return 0;
}

int dots(int count)                             // counts DOWN the number of dots that the int is set as a parameter

{
    for (; count >= 1; count--)                         
    {
        cout << "." ;
    }
    return 0;
}
int dashes(int count)                           // counts UP the number of dots that the int is set as a parameter
{
    int i;
    for (; count >= 1; count--)
    {
        cout << "-";
    }
    return 0;
}                           
void sendSOS()
{
    dots(3);
    dashes(3);
    dots(3);
}
void waitSeconds(int seconds2Wait)                  //Sleeps for time specified

{
    Sleep(1000 * seconds2Wait);                     //converts miliseconds to seconds
    seconds2Wait = 2;
}
int triangle(int rows)                              //Prints a dot triangle
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            cout << ". ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
int slowTriangle(int rows)                              //Prints a dot triangle with sleep paramter passed in
{
    int i, j, seconds2Wait;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
            waitSeconds(3);
        {
            cout << ". ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
void distressCall()
{
    sendSOS();
    waitSeconds(2);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to execute code while the timer is running?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  In my slowTriangle function I am trying to call my sleep function so that it will print my dot triangle slowly, waiting a second before printing each row of dots.

Comment: Perhaps you want a `std::thread` which uses `std::this_thread::sleep_for`. No need to limit the code to a specific platform.

Comment: `int triangle(4);` and the lines below it aren't function calls, they are a declaration of an int named triangle with a value of 4 and two function prototypes.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok, I see now that I missed that they are prototypes. How would I declare them as there own function?

Comment: You already did, the issue is that instead of calling them as you did with `dots`, `dashes`, `sendSOS`, and `waitSeconds` you changed what you were doing so it is syntactically correct but not what you intended to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int dots(int count);
int dashes(int count);
void sendSOS();
void waitSeconds(int seconds2Wait);
int triangle(int rows);
int slowTriangle(int rows);
void distressCall();

int main()
{
    dots(3);
    dashes(3);
    sendSOS();
    cout << "\n\n";
    waitSeconds(1);
    triangle(4);
    slowTriangle(4);
    distressCall();

    return 0;
}

int dots(int count)                             // counts DOWN the number of dots that the int is set as a parameter

{
    for (; count >= 1; count--)
    {
        cout << "." ;
    }
    return 0;
}
int dashes(int count)                           // counts UP the number of dots that the int is set as a parameter
{
    for (; count >= 1; count--)
    {
        cout << "-";
    }
    return 0;
}
void sendSOS()
{
    dots(3);
    dashes(3);
    dots(3);
}
void waitSeconds(int seconds2Wait)                  //Sleeps for time specified
{
    time_t goal = seconds2Wait + time(0);
    while (goal > time(0));
}
int triangle(int rows)                              //Prints a dot triangle
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            cout << ". ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
int slowTriangle(int rows)                              //Prints a dot triangle with sleep paramter passed in
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            waitSeconds(3);
            cout << ". ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
void distressCall()
{
    sendSOS();
    waitSeconds(2);
}
```

Implemented pause function as suggested and it works as intended now. Kudos to our other friend who wrote the ctime pause function. I also fixed some of your syntax errors :)
If you want distressCall() to run forever make it like this:

```
void distressCall()
{
    while(true)
    {
        sendSOS();
        waitSeconds(2);
    }
}
```

Strongly recommend that you implement an escape mechanism though :).

Comment: Yes thank you that is what I suspect I am just unsure of why my output when ran is: ...---...---... and it doesn't reach my functions past waitSeconds?

Comment: Because you were not actually calling the functions.

Comment: Try the code I just changed and see if it works properly now. If you do make infinite wait make sure you IMPLEMENT an escape mechanism.

Comment: @pipja Thank you. On my distressCall it will not continue to call my sendSOS, my program is at a pause it seems.

Comment: do this: replace while() with while(true)

Comment: Downvoted for busy wait. This wastes CPU time and power.

Comment: I think James asked a question that did not involve optimization, even his infinite wait is a recipe for disaster. Your downvote is uncalled for, but that's life on stackoverflow i guess.

Answer (score 3):

The correct C++ answer is already in the comments: `std::this_thread::sleep_for`
The WinAPI method (`Sleep`) is also possible.

The real reason why your "functions" appear to fail is because `int triangle(4)` defines a new variable in `main`, initialized to 4. This variable hides the global `triangle` function.

Comment: His code does not use threads, also I believe he is a beginner thus he mixed up the use of "int" at various locations. I cleaned it up and make it work according to his level of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ctime>
void pause (unsigned int seconds)
{
    time_t goal = seconds + time(0);
    while (goal > time(0));
}
```

Comment: As for the ctime libary there is no way to do this within the <windows.h>?

Comment: It's unwise to make system calls that you don't need to. You probably could, but I'd advise against it.